# How to pass string from VBA to Delphi DLL avoiding ShareMem using?

Tags: vba, delphi, dll

the task is very common and I though it is very easy to complete. But after 3 hours of googling I have gave up.

I have to pass string from MS Access VBA macros to Delphi DLL to operate with the string inside Delphi DLL.

Enviroment: Delphi 2010, Access 2010

I also want to avoid using of ShareMem.

What I do:

**Access:**

```
Option Compare Database

Private Declare Function callForm Lib "C:\Programing\_contract\MyWork_2014\AccessDLL\build\access.dll" (ByRef par As Variant) As Long

Private Sub Button0_Click()
    MsgBox callForm("alex")
End Sub
```

**Delphi DLL:**

```
function callForm(par: PChar): Integer; export; stdcall;
var
  buf: PWideChar;
  s: String;
  rs: RawByteString;
begin
  frmAccessTest.Caption := par;
  frmAccessTest.ShowModal;
  Result := 456;
end;
```

As result I have wrong caption of my form.
What should I fix to get it working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you attempted to use a variant to pass a string. It seems to me to be more sensible to pass a string. Do this by:

1. Changing the VBA `Declare` statement to specify the parameter type to be `ByVal par As String`.
2. Changing the Delphi parameter from `PChar` to `PAnsiChar`. For your Unicode Delphi `PChar` is an alias to `PWideChar`.

As an aside, do note that the Delphi `export` directive is ignored. You should remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Both Delphi and VBA support variants.
Passing the string as a variant in VBA and reading it as a variant in Delphi should solve your problem.

So redefine the Delphi routine as:

```
function callForm(par: Olevariant): Integer; stdcall;
begin
  frmAccessTest.Caption := par;
  frmAccessTest.ShowModal;
  Result := 456;
end;
```

Make sure to A: use `OleVariant` and never return `(Ole)variant` as a result.
If you want to return a result do something like:

```
procedure ReturnAString(A: integer; out B: OleVariant); stdcall;
```

Don't forget to set the parameter passing by `ByVal` in VBA:

```
Private Declare Function callForm Lib "path.dll" (ByVal par As Variant) As Long
```

See also: [How do I (or if I can't) use Variants on simple DLLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667281/how-do-i-or-if-i-cant-use-variants-on-simple-dlls)

Comment: If you use a variant like that then the VBA needs to be ByVal surely

Comment: when I use OleVariant as type for the input parameter my Access instance crashes.

Comment: @mad that's because you had ByRef on VBA but passed by value on Delphi side.